# Who framed/derived the concept of namavali from sahasranama stotra? Is there any reference in vedas that namavali can be used for Sahasranama stotra?

Tags: vedas, puranas, mantras, ganesha, stotra

When there is a sahasranama stotra, why namavali is inferred from it? Did any sages refer to use namavali from sahas stotra in any spiritual texts?  Is it because of the pujas in temples, where the namavali can be used?
I agree that the divine names are same in both but how can someone rephrase that stotra to namavali?

Comment: It's not only sahasranamam stotras from where one can extract namavalies, but infact any stotra. For e.g. Aditya-Hridhyam or Navanag stotram etc.

Comment: You can not get such references from the Vedas as Vedas don't contain Sahsranama Stotras. Such stotras are found only in Puranas (Itihasas) and Tantras.